# Communicate data between WatchOS & Today Extension widget

Tags: swift, watchkit, today-extension

Standard set up for Watch OS > 2.
`WCSessionDelegate` used to coordinte data between main application and Watch.

An App Group `"group.***********.TodayExtensionWidget"` used to coordinate data between main application and its Today Extension widget via `UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.***********.TodayExtensionWidget")`

When I make a change from the watch it communicates that change with the main application. Then the main application (once launched) communicates this on to the Today Extension.
What I would like to do is communicate the change in the watch app to the Today extension without needing to launch the main app first.

Is there a best practice to communicate between a watch app and a Today Extension widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no way to achieve this using any built-in frameworks. Since the introduction of `watchOS2`, `WatchKit` apps are considered to be independent apps and not just an extension of the `iOS` app, hence you cannot use `AppGroups` to share data between the two and especially cannot use it to share data between the `WatchKit` app and an `iOS` extension.

As you already experienced, `WatchConnectivity` cannot be used in a `Today extension`, so that is out of the picture as well.

Your only option is a suboptimal one, since you will need to upload your data to a server from your `watchOS` app and download it in your `iOS Today extension`. This of course generates unnecessary data usage, but with the current frameworks provided by Apple you cannot share the data offline.

However, if you wait until `watchOS4` is released (or give the beta version a try), you might be able to leverage the `CoreBluetooth` framework, which is becoming available for `WatchKit` in `watchOS4` to communicate between a `WatchKit` app and an `iOS` extension offline, using `BLE`. I am not 100% sure if `CoreBluetooth` can be used in `iOS Extensions`, but you should give this a try if you can use `watchOS4 beta`.

Comment: Yeah im building for watchOS4. Im only wanting to send a String so dont think its worth my effort to look into the CoreBluetooth. Was hoping for a Notification centre type solution. I guess ill just wait for Apple to make it possible.