# How to communicate WatchOS & Today Extension widget

Tags: swift, widget, core-bluetooth, watchconnectivity

I'm making widget by Swift. My App also has watchOS App but I couldn't find the way to connect those without opening the host App.

There is same question about one year ago.

> [Communicate data between WatchOS & Today Extension widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752905/communicate-data-between-watchos-today-extension-widget)

At that time, the answer said WatchConnectivity cannot be used in a `Today extension` ,and `CoreBluetooth` can be used in iOS Extensions by watchOS4. Current watchOS is 5, so did it ended up being possible now?? I still couldn't find the way to connect widget and watchOS directly.

Please tell me if there are some documentations or something about that.